# Query specific Elastic Search node

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elastic Search to store large documents. I wish to run specialised large-data queries (which can't be achieved in ES/Lucene) local to the actual data. What I mean by this is I don't want to drag GBs of data over the network only to throw half of it away.

My solution to this is that on each node I will have a Java process that will query the localhost ES instance.

My question is, is it possible to do a query on a specific ES node to only query the shards for which it is the primary node for and not query other nodes aswell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `elasticsearch preferences` to control the preference of which shards to execute the search request on.

```
curl localhost:9200/_search?preference=xyzabc123 -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}'
```

**_primary**

The operation will go and be executed only on the primary shards.

**_primary_first**

The operation will go and be executed on the primary shard, and if not available (failover), will execute on other shards.

**_replica**

The operation will go and be executed only on a replica shard.

**_replica_first**

The operation will go and be executed only on a replica shard, and if not available (failover), will execute on other shards.

**_local**

The operation will prefer to be executed on a local allocated shard if possible.

**_only_node:xyz**

Restricts the search to execute only on a node with the provided node id (xyz in this case).

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html)