# Querying specific Elastic Search Node - Do both does the same or not?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 nodes Elasticsearch cluster with IP addresses of **xx.xx.xx.17(master)** and **xx.xx.xx.18(data)**. I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197375/query-specific-elastic-search-node) is the documented way of searching on preferred replica/node.

The question is, If I send my request targeting **xx.xx.xx.18(data)** node *(as an example- http://xx.xx.xx.18:9200/product/_count)* will the request be querying that specific node?

OR is the only way of querying a preferred node is sending it with the '**preferred**' parameter as in the above link?

Comment: It s depends of shards/replica. Your data are split and node have to communicate each others. So i would keep querry replica first for search but i wont target specific ip myself. The real optimisation would be to use "routing" :  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you send a query to an Elasticsearch node, it will talk to any and all other nodes that hold data for indices that need to be queried. if you have replicas assigned to indices, Elasticsearch will randomly pick between the primary and (n) replica shards

assuming each node of yours holds a full copy of every shard, either primary or replica, this means you might get your response from all shards on that node or not, which is what LeBigCat hints on above

however you can use preference here, yes. but it's not clear what problem you are trying to solve with this

Comment: I wanted to use a data node while indexing. So I wanted to make sure that pointing a data node's IP address would do it or not. Seems like the only way of doing that is using preference parameter. Thank you!